# whats the difference between "getPressed" and "onAction" button properties in xml ribbon code?

Tags: xml, vba, ribbon, adp

Help me please. I am doing adp-project ribbon using xml code.
And i don't understand what is the difference between  "getPressed" and "onAction" button properties?

Answer (score 5):

`OnAction` is similar to its meaning in VBA. When a button is pressed its OnAction subroutine is executed.

`GetPressed`, like `GetVisible`, `GetLabel`, etc., runs when the Ribbon or control is Invalidated, e.g., by calling `Ribbon.Invalidate`. If you have a GetPressed routine for a checkbox, for example, you can then take different actions depending on whether it's checked or not.

[Ken Puls describes](http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2006/11/29/modifying-the-ribbon-part-6/) this better than me.